# How to make open files limits more than 2000000?

Tags: linux, limit, open-files

`/etc/security/limits.conf` contains

```
* soft nofile 2000000
* hard nofile 2000000
```

After I changed the open files limits to 2000000, the system can't login; error message is "permission denied".

If I change the open files limits to 900000, it is OK.

Linux version is 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
6526592
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the system-wide maximum on a running system with a `sysctl`:

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=2000000
```

or stick this line in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make it permanent:

```
fs.file-max = 2000000
```